# How to webscrape url and store data in CSV?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have problem to create CSV file from URL,https://rog.asus.com/motherboards/rog-maximus/rog-maximus-xi-formula-model/spec/. I need to download from page specs about motherboards, for now i have only header generated in python, but I dont know how to download itemcontent. This is what I got to create headers in CSV.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

# Wskazany link
url = "https://rog.asus.com/pl/motherboards/rog-maximus/rog-maximus-xi-formula-model/spec/"

# Pobierz zawartość strony
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# Znajdź wszystkie elementy <div> z odpowiednią klasą
spec_elements = soup.find_all('div', class_='ProductSpecSingle__productSpecItemRow__3sjMJ')

# Nagłówek do zapisania w pliku CSV
header = ['Procesor', 'Chipset', 'Pamięć', 'Grafika', 'Obsługa Multi-GPU',
          'Gniazda rozszerzeń', 'Magazyn danych', 'Sieć LAN', 'Bezprzewodowa sieć']

# Słownik do przechowywania danych specyfikacyjnych
data_dict = {key: '' for key in header}

# Dla każdego elementu <div>
for spec_element in spec_elements:
    # Znajdź element <h2> z odpowiednią klasą
    spec_title_element = spec_element.find('h2', class_='ProductSpecSingle__productSpecItemTitle__8gSrN')
    
    # Znajdź element <span> z odpowiednią klasą
    spec_value_element = spec_element.find('span', class_='ProductSpecSingle__descriptionItemValue__lVa0O')
    
    # Sprawdź, czy elementy zostały znalezione i czy zawierają tekst
    if spec_title_element and spec_value_element and spec_value_element.text.strip():
        # Pobierz tekst z elementów
        spec_title = spec_title_element.text.strip()
        spec_value = spec_value_element.text.strip()
        
        # Sprawdź, czy nagłówek jest w naszej liście nagłówków
        for header_name in header:
            if header_name.lower() in spec_title.lower():
                data_dict[header_name] = spec_value

# Nazwa pliku CSV
csv_filename = 'ASUS/specyfikacja_plyty_glownej.csv'

# Zapisz do pliku CSV z kodowaniem UTF-8
with open(csv_filename, mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    
    # Zapisz nagłówek
    writer.writerow(header)
    
    # Zapisz dane
    writer.writerow([data_dict[header_name] for header_name in header])

print(f'Utworzono plik CSV: {csv_filename} z danymi specyfikacji.')
```

I need to generate CSV with all detalis of Tech Specs using python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main issues here - Check your `response` / `soup` seems that the website is blocking requests, so add a user-agent:

```
response = requests.get(url, headers={'user-agent':'some-agent'})
```

Second, the content is rendered dynamically by `javascript`, what is not support by `requests` - So there are two options:

1. You know the internal id of the product, use the api to request additional information.
2. Extract the information in the script section of the footer and convert it via `json.loads()` and interact it like a `dict`to pick jour information:

   ```
   data = json.loads(json.loads(re.search(r'JSON.parse.*("{.*?}")', response.text).group(1)))
   ```

###### Example

```
import requests, csv, re, json

# Wskazany link
url = "https://rog.asus.com/pl/motherboards/rog-maximus/rog-maximus-xi-formula-model/spec/"

response = requests.get(url, headers={'user-agent':'some-agent'})

data = json.loads(json.loads(re.search(r'JSON.parse.*("{.*?}")', response.text).group(1)))

specs = {e.get('Display_field'):' '.join([d.get('Display_description') for d in e.get('Description')]) for e in data.get('Spec').get('spec')[0].get('Spec_content')}

with open('zzz_my_result.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(specs.keys())
    w.writerow(specs.values())
```